# How to find the count of another group in a group

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, count

I could not explain the problem clearly in the header but here is the issue.

I am using SQL Server.

I have a table that has Universities and Subjects.

```
University     Subject

Melbourne      Math
Melbourne      Physics
Melbourne      English

Ottawa         Physics
Ottawa         English
Ottawa         Arts
Ottawa         Computer

Sydney         Math
Sydney         Medicine
Sydney         English
Sydney         Computer
.
.
.
```

I want to do some calculations in one select statement

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT Subject, Count(*) SubjectsCount
FROM Table
GROUP BY Subject
```

Gives

```
Subject SubjectsCount
Math       39
Physics    23
English    47
Medicine   13
```

I want to fnd number of distinct Universities in the same query

```
Subject SubjectsCount UniversitiesNo 
Math       39           52
Physics    23           52
English    47           52
Medicine   13           52
```

I tried this

```
SELECT Subject, Count(*) SubjectsCount, Count(*) OVER() AS UniversitiesNo
FROM Table
GROUP BY Subject
```

but this gave all records count

How can I specify for Universities distinct only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can CROSS JOIN a query that returns the number of all distinct universities:

```
SELECT t.Subject, 
       COUNT(*) SubjectsCount,
       u.UniversitiesNo 
FROM tablename t 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT University) UniversitiesNo FROM tablename) u
GROUP BY t.Subject, u.UniversitiesNo
```

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT Subject, 
       COUNT(*) SubjectsCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT University) FROM tablename) UniversitiesNo 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Subject
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f129731784ec6277ecebd98d694406c2).

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT Subject
   , Count(*) SubjectsCount
   , Count(DISTINCT University) AS UniversitiesNo
FROM Table
GROUP BY Subject
```

This query gives the number of distinct universites per `Subject`.

To get distinct number of universities simply `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.Subject,
       t1.SubjectsCount,
       t2.cnt
FROM (       
   SELECT Subject, Count(*) SubjectsCount         
   FROM Table1  
  GROUP BY Subject
) AS  t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT University) FROM Table1) AS t2(cnt)
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ef2b/5)

Comment: I want the count of all universities not just for the subject, Count(*)  gives the number of universities as each subject is unique per uni